# Unique paths to leaf node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Assuming that my graph looks like this

[image]

Which can be generated using

```
MERGE (O: DeliveryHead { name: 'O' })
MERGE (A: Manager { name: 'A' })
MERGE (B: Lead { name: 'B' })
MERGE (C: Engineer { name: 'C' })
MERGE (X: Manager { name: 'X' })
MERGE (Y: Engineer { name: 'Y' })
MERGE (L: Engineer { name: 'L' })
MERGE (A)-[:RELATED_TO]->(B)
MERGE (B)-[:RELATED_TO]->(C)
MERGE (X)-[:RELATED_TO]->(Y)
MERGE (O)-[:RELATED_TO]->(A)
MERGE (O)-[:RELATED_TO]->(B)
MERGE (O)-[:RELATED_TO]->(C)
MERGE (O)-[:RELATED_TO]->(X)
MERGE (O)-[:RELATED_TO]->(Y)
MERGE (O)-[:RELATED_TO]->(L)
```

- I would like to find all unique paths between `DeliveryHead` and `Engineer`.
- It is also assumed that there can be `0` to `n` number of designations between `DeliverHead` and `Engineer` and are not just restricted to `Manager` as mentioned above.
- The leaf node will always be `Engineer`

For the above graph, the expected output should be

```
O-->X-->Y
O-->A-->B-->C
O-->L
```

Comment: It is not clear why you should get the output. E.g. why `0 --> X --> Y` and not `O --> Y`?

Comment: @frant.hartm, I am basically wanting to know all the hierarchy inside an organisation. Considering `engineer` is my leaf node, i want all the unique hierarchies that lead to the position of an `engineer`

Comment: If it helps, I can assume that I know what is the order of the hierarchy. i.e, I know manager should be above TL and TL should be above engineer. Even in case of dynamic `n` designations between `organisation` and `engineer`, it can be assumed that I know their order

Answer (score 0):

A variable-length match should get you what you want. Something like this:

```
MATCH p = (:DeliveryHead)-[:RELATED_TO*]->(:Engineer)
RETURN p
```

If you just want the names of the nodes in the path, then you can extract and return those:

```
MATCH p = (:DeliveryHead)-[:RELATED_TO*]->(:Engineer)
RETURN [node in nodes(p) | node.name] as path
```

EDIT

To filter only to the longest paths between the start :DeliveryHead and each end :Engineer node, you'll need to do some ordering of the path lengths and grab the first of the collected ordered paths:

```
MATCH p = (d:DeliveryHead)-[:RELATED_TO*]->(e:Engineer)
WITH d, e, p
ORDER BY length(p) DESC
WITH d, e, head(collect(p)) as longestPath
RETURN [node in nodes(longestPath) | node.name] as path
```

Comment: According to the above image,
Won't the above query will return 
O-->A-->B-->C | O-->A-->C | O-->C
Where as, id only want 
O-->A-->B-->C 
as the result

Comment: I guess I'm missing why that would be your only desired result. Is there a requirement that the first relationship should be to a :Manager node? I think I'm either missing or have overlooked some part of your requirements.

Comment: I guess putting it this way might give it some more meaning. The requirement is to find the path between :Organization and :Engineer where there could be n nodes (all of different labels) between them. Also make sure that the path is the longest between :Organization and the leaf :Engineer node and only return the longest path leading to that leaf node.

Comment: Hey @InverseFalcon, thanks for updating the answer but this still doesn't give me the entire result set. I think its still confusing. What i meant was that I want all the longest paths leading to ALL leaf nodes and not just THE longest path in the entire graph.

All the possible subpaths from O leading to node C are
O>A>B>C, O>B>C, O>C
All the possible subpaths from O leading to node Y are
O>X>Y, O>Y
And all the subpaths from O leading to node L are
O>L

So the result should have all the longest paths to all the leaf nodes which would mean O>A>B>C, O>X>Y and O>L only

Comment: Your query did lead me to something but i am still a bit short of the final result.

`MATCH p = (:DeliveryHead)-[:RELATED_TO*]->(e :Employee)
WITH reduce(acc =[], n IN nodes(p) | CASE WHEN n.name = e.name THEN acc + nodes(p) ELSE acc END) AS pathsToLeafNode, e
ORDER BY length(pathsToLeafNode) DESC
RETURN pathsToLeafNode, e`

But i'd want to call the head function on each record against employee
So technically, id want the result to be something like
RETURN {employee: e, path: head(pathsToLeafNode)} but head(pathsToLeafNode) should be called for every e node